# GetRasterBand() method for gdal in Python

Tags: gdal, python-2.7, osgeo

I was going through a tutorial book called [Python Geospatial Development](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/python-geospatial-development-second-edition). On the chapter on using working with geospatial data in python there is an example of a script meant to handle and analysis raster data for the height values. I ran the following code:

```
import sys, struct
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import gdalconst


minLat = -48
maxLat = -33
minLong = 165
maxLong = 179

dataset = gdal.Open("l10g")
band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)

t = dataset.GetGeoTransform()
success,tInverse = gdal.InvGeoTransform(t)
if not success:
    print("Failed!")
    sys.exit(1)

x1, y1= gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(tInverse, minLong, minLat)
x2, y2= gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(tInverse, maxLong, maxLat)

minX = int(min(x1, x2))
maxX = int(max(x1, x2))
minY = int(min(y1, y2))
maxY = int(max(y1, y2))

width = (maxX - minX) + 1
fmt = "<" + ("h"* width)

for y in range(minY, maxY+1):
    scanline = band.ReadRaster(minX, y, width, 1, width, 1,
                               gdalconst.GDT_Int16)
    values = struct.unpack(fmt, scanline)

    for values in values:
        try:
            histogram[value] += 1
        except KeyError:
            histogram[value] = 1
for height in sorted(histogram.keys()):
    print (height, hsitogram[height])
```

but I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Progies\Geospatial\l10g\histogram.py", line 12, in <module>
    band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'
```

Comment: The dataset is 'NoneType' because "l10g" is not a valid raster. It's a directory where is **histogram.py**. Wich is the true raster's path?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was able to solve the problem. I was missing the header file for the DEM image which should be in the same directory as the DEM image file.

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to clarify that "l10g" is a DEM tile from the [GLOBE website](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/topo/gltiles.html) ([Python Geospatial Development](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/topo/gltiles.html), p.120) and is a valid raster (raw elevation data). You must also download the hdr (l10g.hdr, book p.120 and explanations of Gabor Farkas)

The l10g, l10g.hdr and histogram.py files should be in the same folder D:\Python\Progies\Geospatial\l10g\

To open "l10g", you must open your shell in this folder. If not you must adjust the path of the files

```
dataset = gdal.Open("l10g")
```

or for example

```
dataset = gdal.Open("D:/Python/Progies/Geospatial/l10g/l10g")
```

To verify that dataset is not None (no file open -> NoneType)

```
print dataset.GetGeoTransform()
(90.000000000000497, 0.0083333333329999992, 0.0, -5.000002148425331e-13, 0.0, -0.0083333333329999992)
print dataset.RasterCount()
1
print dataset.GetRasterBand(1).XSize
10800
print dataset.GetRasterBand(1).YSize
6000
```

Now, you can execute your script without the `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'` error

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was able to solve the problem. I was missing the header file for the DEM image which should be in the same directory as the DEM image file. Almost gave me a headache.

Answer (score 2):

This code (modified to include any datatype) uses the raster loaded directly as active Layer in QGIS (see next image):

```
import sys, struct
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import gdalconst
import os

minLat = -48
maxLat = -33
minLong = 165
maxLong = 179

layer = iface.activeLayer()
provider = layer.dataProvider()

fmttypes = {'Byte':'B', 'UInt16':'H', 'Int16':'h', 'UInt32':'I', 
            'Int32':'i', 'Float32':'f', 'Float64':'d'}

path= provider.dataSourceUri()

(raiz, filename) = os.path.split(path)

dataset = gdal.Open(path)

band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)

t = dataset.GetGeoTransform()
success,tInverse = gdal.InvGeoTransform(t)
if not success:
    print("Failed!")
    sys.exit(1)

x1, y1= gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(tInverse, minLong, minLat)
x2, y2= gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(tInverse, maxLong, maxLat)

minX = int(min(x1, x2))
maxX = int(max(x1, x2))
minY = int(min(y1, y2))
maxY = int(max(y1, y2))

width = (maxX - minX) + 1

BandType = gdal.GetDataTypeName(band.DataType)

print BandType

histogram = {}

for y in range(minY, maxY+1):

    scanline = band.ReadRaster(minX, 
                               y, 
                               width, 
                               1, 
                               width, 
                               1,
                               band.DataType)

    values = struct.unpack(fmttypes[BandType] * width, scanline)

    for value in values:
        try:
            histogram[value] += 1
        except KeyError:
            histogram[value] = 1

for height in sorted(histogram.keys()):
    print (height, histogram[height])
```

The l10g and l10g.hdr files loaded in QGIS:

[image]

It works nice (see image below) when I ran the code in the Python Console:

[image]

**Editing Note:** I found one error in the original post (`for values in values:`). Now, It works nice!

Comment: This is the link to the equivalent code in the original post: [http://pastebin.com/dSsUL30z](http://pastebin.com/dSsUL30z). Only it must be changed the path to l10g and l10g.hdr files.

Comment: Thanks @xunilk the missing header file was the main problem giving the non type error. But your alternative code gives me good insight as a learning developer. I will be comparing above and what I have to compare functionality and ease. Certainly, new learning tools.

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems with your code/approach, which I would like to help to resolve in a quick and explicit manner:

1. The raster data cannot be processed by the algorithm on its own. It needs a header file to access georeference information. Header files can be downloaded from [here](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/topo/elev/esri/hdr/) for the example dataset, as stated on page 120.
2. You have to declare `histogram` prior to filling it up with data. You can do it by adding the following line before the iteration:

   `histogram = {}`
3. You mistyped `histogram` on line 43. It isn't a big deal, but it have to be fixed for the algorithm to run.

[image]

Comment: Both of your observations were true. After solving the header file error I came upon the other errors which were easy to identify from the error logs. The missing header file was the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you already pointed out, you tried to use wrong paths.

The following is my fault:  I input the wrong outputpath (it should be `E:\pytest\testforG\L10622\L1data.tif`
while I input  `E:\pytest\testforG\resize0622\resize0622.tif`, which didn't exist)

I want to write a tif file with gdal as the followings:

def writeTif(data,outputpath):
    if 'int8' in data.dtype.name:
        datatype = gdal.GDT_Byte
    elif 'int16' in data.dtype.name:
        datatype = gdal.GDT_UInt16
    elif 'float32' in data.dtype.name:
        datatype = gdal.GDT_Float32
    else:
        datatype = gdal.GDT_Float64

```
if len(data.shape) == 3:
    bands,height,width = data.shape
else:
    bands,(height,width) = 1,data.shape

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
```

Because I made the wrong outputpath here,  I got an error as:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'

```
dataset = driver.Create(outputpath,width,height,bands,datatype)

if(dataset != None):
    dataset.SetGeoTransform([73.445, 0.04, 0.0, 53.565, 0.0, -0.04])
if bands == 1:
    dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(data)
else:
    for i in range(bands):
        dataset.GetRasterBand(i+1).WrtieArray(data[i])

dataset.FlushCache()
del dataset
driver = None

return None
```

Hope this shed some more like on the problem.